# @RolesAllowed vs request.isUserInRole() on spring boot rest controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am currently working on spring boot rest controller and wondering which form of roles check  should i use and what are the difference between these two.

**Option 1:**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getmypage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @RolesAllowed({"TEST_ROLE"}) 
    public String  getMessage(Model model )  {

      //my code goes here

      }
```

**option 2:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getmypage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String  getMessage(Model model,  HttpServletRequest request )  {

   if (request.isUserInRole("TEST_ROLE")){
        //my code goes here
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not a good idea to check security constraints programmatically in you controllers or services. As one of the most important thing [`AOP`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) tries to achieve, separating [`Cross Cutting Conscerns`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) from your business logic, makes your code more maintainable and doesn't let them to be scattered all over your code.

So in my opinion it's better to choose Option1.

Comment: thank you. But can you help me understand what are the difference between these two approaches.

Comment: If you check security programmatically, you should handle what happens when request is not allowed and send the proper response (`HTTP` status code and message and ...) to the client. But in declarative way, your framework (`Spring Security`) will take care of that. Also your codes to check the request and handle the response will scatter all over your code which make it hard to maintain and change if it's necessary in future.